# how to do the mean of two dataframes columns to be subtrated "mean(df1$a-df2$b)" in r

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, mean, subtraction

My two dataframes looks like this:

```
> dput(head(df1,25))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16644, 16645, 16646, 16647, 
16648, 16649, 16650, 16651, 16652, 16653, 16654, 16655, 16656, 
16657, 16658, 16659, 16660, 16661, 16662, 16663, 16664, 16665, 
16666, 16667, 16668), class = "Date"), AU = c(0.241392906920806, 
0.257591745069017, 0.263305712230276, NaN, 0.252892547032525, 
0.251771180928526, 0.249211746794207, 0.257289083109259, 0.205017582640463, 
0.20072274573488, 0.210154167590338, 0.207384553271337, 0.193725450540089, 
0.199282601988984, 0.216267134143314, 0.217052471451736, NaN, 
0.220703029531909, 0.2164619798534, 0.223442036108148, 0.22061326758891, 
NaN, 0.277777461504811, NaN, 0.200839628485262)), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(head(df2,25))
structure(list(UF1 = c(0.2559, 0.2565, 0.257, 0.2577, 0.2583, 
0.259, 0.2596, 0.2603, 0.2611, 0.2618, 0.2625, 0.2633, 0.2641, 
0.2649, 0.2657, 0.2665, 0.2674, 0.2682, 0.2691, 0.27, 0.2709, 
0.2718, 0.2727, 0.2736, 0.2745), UF2 = c(0.2597, 0.2602, 0.2608, 
0.2614, 0.2621, 0.2627, 0.2634, 0.2641, 0.2648, 0.2655, 0.2663, 
0.267, 0.2678, 0.2686, 0.2694, 0.2702, 0.2711, 0.2719, 0.2728, 
0.2737, 0.2745, 0.2754, 0.2763, 0.2773, 0.2782), UF3 = c(0.2912, 
0.2915, 0.2918, 0.2922, 0.2926, 0.293, 0.2934, 0.2938, 0.2943, 
0.2947, 0.2952, 0.2957, 0.2962, 0.2968, 0.2973, 0.2979, 0.2985, 
0.2991, 0.2997, 0.3003, 0.3009, 0.3016, 0.3022, 0.3029, 0.3035
), Date = structure(c(16644, 16645, 16646, 16647, 16648, 16649, 
16650, 16651, 16652, 16653, 16654, 16655, 16656, 16657, 16658, 
16659, 16660, 16661, 16662, 16663, 16664, 16665, 16666, 16667, 
16668), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

I want to do the mean of two different dataframes columns subtracting (**mean(df1$AU-df2$UF)**).
The closest to the solution I got is the following:

```
data.frame(mean = colMeans(df1$AU, na.rm = TRUE) - colMeans(df2$UF))
```

but I got this error:

```
Error in colMeans(df1$mAU, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

I succeed to run the same code only for dataframes with one column each, but since I have 3 or more columns per dataframe I want calculate against `df1$AU` I need to be more efficient.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are 3 columns `UF1`, `UF2` and `UF3` but no `UF`.

Comment: I think the question needs clarification. Are you looking for the difference between the means? The mean of the differences? something else..? Each of these would require a different approach based on your data.

Comment: I did some edit on my question. I want "mean(df1$AU-df2$UF" instead of "mean=(df1$AU-df2$UF"  which means the difference between the means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you meant is that you want the subtraction of the means of the (numeric) columns in `df1` with the mean of the (numeric) columns in `df2`, this can be done like this:

```
mean(df1$AU, na.rm = T) - colMeans(df2[,1:3], na.rm = T)
```

this outputs:

```
       UF1        UF2        UF3 
-0.0367389 -0.0404509 -0.0688949
```

per column of the `df2`

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: It depends on the wanted output, since the question was quite vague, I suggested a general solution.

Comment: You're right, the question is vague. I will delete my previous comment and post another one, better explained.

Comment: If the `NA`'s or `NaN`'s are in different places or if there are more of them in one vector than in others, the vector element wise differences won't be the same. I believe that it makes more sense to assume the OP wants the differences `x[1]-y[1]`, `x[2]-y[2]`, etc, then the mean of this vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two base R functions to compute the mean of the differences. The 2nd is faster.

```
meanDiffs1 <- function(x, y, na.rm = TRUE){
  z <- if(na.rm) na.omit(cbind(x, -1*y)) else cbind(x, -1*y)
  mean(rowSums(z))
}
meanDiffs2 <- function(x, y, na.rm = TRUE){
  if(na.rm){
    i <- is.na(x)
    j <- is.na(y)
    mean(x[!i & !j] - y[!i & !j])
  } else {
    mean(x - y)
  }
}

meanDiffs(df1$AU, df2$UF1)
#[1] -0.0361429
meanDiffs2(df1$AU, df2$UF1)
#[1] -0.0361429
```

To compute all mean differences between `df1$AU` and `df$UF*`, use `sapply`.

```
sapply(df2[1:3], \(y) meanDiffs2(df1$AU, y))
#        UF1         UF2         UF3 
#-0.03614290 -0.03986195 -0.06848576
```